# How do I write a Rails finder method that counts instances of a field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, ruby-on-rails-5, finder

I'm using Rails 5.  I have a model with

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_many :emails
```

How do I write a finder method that locates all the users who have more than one email?  I can't seem to figure out how to use "count" in a where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will join on the emails table and return users having a count of more than one.

```
scope :with_more_than_one_email, -> {
  joins(:emails).having('COUNT(emails) > 1').group(:id)
}
```

You can invoke it with `User.with_more_than_one_email`